# Go back / finish function directly in called onClick, without further code

Tags: android, android-xml

I know I can have something like:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/zoomImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="goBack"
    android:src="@drawable/zoom_selector" />
```

and then a function like

```
public void goBack(View v){
    finish();
}
```

but I was wondering if there is any key/reserved word to do exactly that, without having to create my own function. Something like

```
android:onClick="reservedWordThatFinishesTheCurrentActivity"
```

I´m curious about it. :)

Comment: there is no such key/reserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no way to do so and, therefore, I will carry on with my life, as suggested in one of the comments.